# Ошибка при сборке проекта в Android (конфликт Jack и Java 8)

Tags: android, gradle, apache-poi, java-8

Пытаюсь собрать проект, в котором подключена библиотека Apache POI 3.15 и включен `multidex`.

Однако, при сборке выбивает ошибку:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Jack is required to support java 8 language features.
Jack is required to support java 8 language features.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid121Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: D:\Projects\Reminderofwork\app\src\main\java\com\rostislav\dugin\reminderofwork\XLSXHelper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileRetrolambdaDebug
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:when not building a core library.
Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:going on.
Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Error:1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\SDK\jdk_8\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Мой `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rostislav.dugin.reminderofwork"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.15'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.15'
}
```

---

В чем проблема и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что:

> Jack is required to support java 8 language features.

То есть для использования конструкций из `java 8` необходим `Java Android Compiler Kit`.

В `defaultConfig` добавьте:

```
jackOptions {
    enabled true
}
```

Кстати, `JACK` поддерживает `multidex`, поэтому, скорее всего, при его использовании Вы не получите ошибки `65k method limit` даже при неиспользовании `com.android.support:multidex`.

Comment: А что это дает? P.S. API 21 выставлен на время, компилировать буду под Android 4.2.

Comment: @bukashka101, Таким образом Вы *включите* `JACK`, который от Вас требуют.

Comment: Тогда у меня осталос два вопроса: если я поставлю Java 7 - проблема пропадёт? И, если я включу поддержку Jack, не пропадет ли поддержка Android 4.2?

Comment: @bukashka101, Если Вы отключите поддержку `Java 8`, эта проблема пропадет, но возникнет другая, которая будет связана с тем, что Вы используете конструкции из `Java 8` на меньшей версии. По второму – скорее всего пропадет, ибо поддержка `Java 8` добавлена в `Android N`. Хотя тут точно сказать не могу.

Comment: В предшествующем комментарии под поддержкой `Java 8` подразумевается **поддержка только лишь некоторых фич** из `Java 8`.

Comment: Я поставил Java 7 (она мне не нужна, у меня библиотека для поддержки функций Java 8 из Java 7), но проблема осталась.

Comment: @bukashka101, Какая это такая библиотека?

Comment: https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda

Comment: @bukashka101, Вообще странно это все. Но может быть Вы используете какие-либо конструкции из `Java 8`, поддержку которых не предоставляет эта библиотека?

Comment: Нет. Только лямбды и все. А с чего вы взяли, что проблема в Java 8?

Comment: @bukashka101, С того, что при сборке Вы получаете `Jack is required to support java 8 language features.`.

Comment: Оу, ошибка изменилась. Я не заметил. Это уже будет другой вопрос.